# Setting the DataContext of a RichEditBox in a C# WinRT app

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-runtime, datacontext

I would like to bind the contents of a RichEditBox in a WinRT app, the RichEditBox.Document property, to a string or object that can be easily accessed and changed by another page of the app, with the changes appearing in the RichEditBox.

I've tried using the following:

```
EditorBox.DataContext = EditorBoxContent;

public ITextDocument EditorBoxContent { get; set; }
```

But I'm must be setting the object incorrectly. When I try to poll EditorBoxContent from another page, the app crashes. The error message says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access a control on a page from a different page so the error pops up.
If you just want to pass a string value make use of Query String during navigation.
Or you can try to use a static variable on the page and access that variable on the other page and change its value. Hope that solved your problem.